# How can I access the ViewModel bound to a different element in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a situation where I have a component that needs to access the model of a different component and set a flag.

So, something similar to this:

```
<div id='component1'>
    <div data-bind='visible: showMe()'>Shown</div>
</div>

<div id='component2'>
    <button data-bind='click: setFlag()'>Set the flag</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function () {
    var vm1 = {
        showMe: ko.observable(false)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm1, $("#component1"));
})();

(function () {
    var vm2 = {
        setFlag: function () {
            // How to set showMe to true in vm1                
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(vm2, $("#component2"));
})();
```

Comment: This blog post has some interesting alternatives on dealing with multiple view models scenarios: http://www.wrapcode.com/communication-between-multiple-view-models-in-knockoutjs-mvvm-the-right-approach/

Comment: you can decalre `showMe` in the common scope with this setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I assume `#component1` is a partial view-like thing which depends on `#component2`. but since it is not directly embedded inside `#component1` there must be some common container which holds them both. This common container should be thought of as a host of both components.

In general, you should always wrap logically interrelated parts of the UI in a common container and define a viewmodel for that container which does nothing else but holds the viewmodels of the individual parts or components, whatever you like, and perhaps some coordination logic like defining what is visible and when, just like in your question.

So I would go about it like the following:

```
function component1ViewModel() {

};

function component2ViewModel() {

};

function mainViewModel() {
    var self = this;        

    // Doesn't have to be observable if the value is never changed        
    this.component1VM = ko.observable(new component1ViewModel());
    this.component2VM = ko.observable(new component2ViewModel());

    this.component1Visible = ko.observable(false);
    this.setComponent1Visible = function(visible) {
        self.component1Visible(visible);
    };
};
```

Then in your markup:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="component1" data-bind="with: component1VM, visible: $parent.component1Visible()">
    Yay I'm visible!
  </div>

  <div id="component2" data-bind="with: component2VM">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.setComponent1Visible.bind($data, true)">
      Show component 1
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, the initialization:

```
$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new mainViewModel(), $('#main')[0]);
});
```

So to sum it up, by wrapping the two interdependent viewmodels in a common container, you can use the `$parent` element knockout provides you with in your markup, and using that reference, you can call functions in upper-level objects in the viewmodel hierarchy.

I would like to note, however, that using this approach you can call directly into `component1` if you so desire by adding the proper navigation: `$parent.component1.someFunction.bind($data, val1, val2)`. So in fact, you are not limited to defining the visibility-related things in the common parent, you can use whichever approach you like better and find more readable.